# "Quarterly Franklin Membership" means?

Tags: journals, disreputable-publishers

Recently I received an email from London Journals Press.

> Dear Dr. Po-Wei Huang,
>
> ...
>
> Taking note of your research interest that matches with our journal scope, I would like to welcome you to associate with us. To follow this, our Editorial Board has agreed to recognise you under "Quarterly Franklin Membership" (Membership ID#XC11296).
>
> ...
>
> Also I encourage you to have your upcoming research article/paper published in our international, peer-reviewed, refereed journal, London Journal of Engineering Research (LJER) and confirm your review slot before 15th of the coming month for the next issue. ...

At first, I ignored it. But after few days, he sent a follow up email like the following,

> I’m writing this as a follow-up for my email which I sent few days ago. I think that you had a glimpse of our Franklin Membership email and our proposal for your membership ID #XC11296. I did not hear back from you since then. If you have any queries regarding the Quarterly Franklin Membership honored to you, I (or my support teammate) would be grateful to provide you with further information.
>
> I hope you don't find this outreach uncomfortable. I was simply wondering if you are still interested in joining our member community. I truly feel that someone like you who is involved in many great research works is ideal for connecting.

I find that London Journals Press is not on the list of predatory journals. So, is there Any recommendation? or should I ask my advisor directly?

Comment: @Anyon, it looks like the site might have changed?

Comment: @Aruralreader Well, it's been four years. I suspect that particular site was discontinued, but archived versions of its list [exist](https://web.archive.org/web/20211105043441/https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's spam: They gave you a free membership to rope you in, in hopes that you will pay for more memberships and/or publish with their journals. Don't fall for it. Just because this particular publisher isn't listed in one particular list
does not mean that they are acting respectfully and ethically.